# Can't figure out why my images are not aligned center (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

here's the site: http://www.whattheyuse.net/alivecor-kardia-mobile-ecg-review/

They are aligned centered in wordpress and in css, I don't understand why they don't show centered (when the width is large enough).

Edit: I was able to fix it, the problem was that I had width: 75% on and aligned center. I just removed width 75%.

Comment: They're centre aligned for me.

Comment: They're image elements. Using `text-align` or `margin: auto` center may help fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paragraph tag surrounding your images, simply set the styles of those to `text-align: center`.

```html
<p style="text-align: center"><a href="https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B01A4W8AUK/whattheyuse-20/" target="_blank"><img class="size-full wp-image-1536 aligncenter size-big" src="http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1.jpg" alt="" width="75%" height="auto" srcset="http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1.jpg 2189w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-300x281.jpg 300w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-768x720.jpg 768w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-1024x959.jpg 1024w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-660x618.jpg 660w" sizes="(max-width: 2189px) 100vw, 2189px"></a></p>
```

(Without)

```html
<p><a href="https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B01A4W8AUK/whattheyuse-20/" target="_blank"><img class="size-full wp-image-1536 aligncenter size-big" src="http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1.jpg" alt="" width="75%" height="auto" srcset="http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1.jpg 2189w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-300x281.jpg 300w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-768x720.jpg 768w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-1024x959.jpg 1024w, http://www.whattheyuse.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Kardia1-660x618.jpg 660w" sizes="(max-width: 2189px) 100vw, 2189px"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your css you have this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
img.size-big, .wp-caption.caption-big {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-bottom: 1.7778em;
    max-width: 780px;
}
```

delete this:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -60px;
```